# Using grep in shell script to search for exact string

Tags: linux, shell-script, grep

I have a `shell script` that checks to see if a name has been added to a text file before it runs that part of the script. If it does find that name it skips this section of the script.

Here is an example of the conflict:

**Netherlands Antillies**

```
if ! grep "netherlands-antilles" uploaded.txt; then
    // Do some work here
    echo netherlands-antilles >> uploaded.txt
fi
```

**Netherlands**

```
if ! grep "netherlands" uploaded.txt; then
    // Do some work here
    echo netherlands >> uploaded.txt
fi
```

Because `Netherlands Antillies` is already in the text file, it doesn't run the "Netherlands" part of the script, which I really need it to.

**Is there a way to have `grep` not just search for part of the string? I don't want a search for `netherlands` to match `netherlands-antilles`.**

Comment: Do you only want to match if `netherlands` is the entire line?  Or do you also want to match if a line contains eg. `netherlands # some comment`?

Comment: See the `-x` and `-F` option of `grep`.

Comment: @JigglyNaga I want to match is netherlands is the entire line. So that the `netherlands` grep would never match `netherlands-antilles`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these entries are the only thing on the line of this file you could use a regular expression to include the start of the line and enf of the line:

```
if ! grep "^netherlands$" uploaded.txt; then
// Do some work here
echo netherlands >> uploaded.txt
fi
```